# Entity not mapped to a single property error with inherited entites of one table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities **SuperAlbumEntity** and **AlbumEntity** reflecting the same table *"albums"*.

**SuperAlbumEntity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "albums")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class SuperAlbumEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    //other fields
}
```

**AlbumEntity**:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "albums")
public class AlbumEntity extends SuperEntity{

    //some fields

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_name", referencedColumnName = "country")
    private Set<CountryEntity> countrySet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**AlbumEntity** has *@OneToMany* mapping to **CountryEntity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
public class CountryEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    String id;

    String country_name;

    //other fields
}
```

Running my application I get the folowing error:

```
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(country) of CountryEntity.countrySet referencing AlbumEntity not mapped to a single property
...
```

What's interesting is that if I move **country** field from **SuperAlbumEntity** to **AlbumEntity** everything just works fine...
Can someone explain me why I get this error?

Comment: i see the countrySet is an Set of ContryEntity? this would be the issue

Comment: Yes, it's a set of CountryEntity because I have a @OneToMany mapping

Comment: @Omar Amaoun, if I change "countrySet" to "country" everything works fine, but I didn't get why...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think is connected with the type of inherence that you used it. Try to modify your superclass to something like this:

**SuperAlbumEntity:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class SuperAlbumEntity {

}
```

**AlbumEntity:**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "albums")
public class AlbumEntity extends SuperEntity {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_name", referencedColumnName = "country")
    private Set<CountryEntity> countrySet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately